# Flexbox filter issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox that follows the width: `calc(100% / 3);` css. This fits well in screen if there are over 6 divs. However, I have a filtering system, so potentially the user can filter and show only 2 divs. This then shows a lot of white space, does anyone have any ideas how I can get around this?

On Filter I have tried changing the width, but this goes out of the 3x2 design we are after. Please see the design here http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems/category/finance/#blogs-filter

```css
.tiles .tile {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(1n) {
  flex-basis: calc(50% / 1);
}

.tiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles" id="blog-posts">
  <div class="tile scale-anm all successstories" style="background-image: url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/finance6.jpg'); right: 0px;">
    dsf
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm all successstories" style="background-image: url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/finance5.jpg'); right: 0px;">
    sdf
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm all successstories" style="background-image: url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/finance6.jpg'); right: 0px;">
    dsf
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm all successstories" style="background-image: url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/finance5.jpg'); right: 0px;">
    sdf
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm all successstories" style="background-image: url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/finance6.jpg'); right: 0px;">
    dsf
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm all successstories" style="background-image: url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/finance5.jpg'); right: 0px;">
    sdf
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should replace the `&quot;` in the inline styles with literal `'` characters

Comment: This? https://jsfiddle.net/w3r0jvfm/

Comment: @Michael_B but if the user is to remove 3 of the tile(s) in the frontend, this just displays as a row and not 2 rows underneath eachother